# Comment Posted but OAuthException Returned

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using the official Facebook PHP SDK to interact with the graph API. According to the Facebook documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/object/comments), I'm using the following API method to post a comment to a Facebook wall post:

```
public function post_comment($id, $comment) {
    $publish = $this->facebook->api("/$id/comments", "post", array('message' => $comment));
    return $publish;
 }
```

The comment is successfully posted to Facebook: I can see it on Facebook's website after posting it, however the API itself returns:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught OAuthException: An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.

Which in turn causes my server to return a 500 internal server error.

Given that the comment successfully posts, I don't see how there can be an OAuth exception?

Any help would be gratefully accepted.

**EDIT:**

I ran the same methods on Facebook's Graph API explorer, and got the same output. The comment *posted fine*, but the graph explorer threw the `Uncaught OAuthException` error, too. I have all the default permissions selected, including `publish_stream` and `publish_actions`. The specific output was:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.", 
      "type": "OAuthException", 
      "code": 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Strange! Can you share the post_id if its public. And did you tried with other posts as well?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not a public post, however I have tried with multiple posts on multiple profiles, and all return the same error, but still post the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Hey here you go with some demo code.
The `$POST_ID` thingy must be set by you ofc.

```
 try{
     $response = $facebook->api("/".$POST_ID."/comments","POST",array (
       'message' => 'This is a test comment',
       )
     );
 }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
 error_log($e->getMessage());
 }
```

Comment: Hey, I've compared our two code samples, and this looks pretty much exactly like what I have. I tried adding the variable outside the quote, but I still get the same error.

Comment: @BnMcG sorry, forgot to paste the surrounding `try{ } catch(FacebookApiException $e){}`

Comment: I added the try/catch block, and it just throws the error I stated in my original post: "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later." I've added some information to my question, see if it helps.